# Remove leading spaces with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have file(list6.txt) which looks like:

```
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx;

xxxxxx xxxxx PxxxxxxxxFxxxxxx xxxxxxx PxxxxxxxxFxxxxxx {

    @Oxxxxxxx
    xxxxxx Sxxxxx xxxNxxx() {
        xxxxxx "Pxxxx_Pxxxxxxxx";
    }

    @Oxxxxxxx
    xxxxxx Pxxxxxxxx xxxxxxPxxxxxxxx(Cxxxxxx xxx) {
        xxxxxx xxx Pxxxxxxxx(xxx);
    }

}
```

I am trying to remove all leading spaces with command:

```
cat list6.txt | sed 's/^[ \t]//'
OR
sed 's/^[ \t]*//' list6.txt
```

However i cant do it with above 2 commands.

Could someone help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: Your second command should work well.  What's the problem?

Comment: It gives me the same output without removing the leading spaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this more portable sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[[:space:]]*//' file
```

This works with both gnu-sed and BSD sed as well.

Comment: Your sed command will run fine on gnu-sed but as I wrote that sed on BSD systems such as OSX doesn't support `\t` for tab character. Using `[[:space]]` is much more portable and it will work with all flavors of sed on different systems.

Comment: So `[[:space:]]` is more portable than `\t`. I did not know it, good one!

Comment: @fedorqui Can't be, because OP reported my one is working for him too

Comment: I am using macbook pro, may be thats the reason. Is there a command to check if mine is BSD shell

Comment: Yes Mac osx is BSD sed and I am also using same macbook and `\t` didn't work for me as well. And yes you can check other online references as well that [[:space:]] is much more portable than other options.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*\(.*$\)/\1/' your.file
```

It will match everything behind the leading spaces in matching group 1. In the replacement pattern just this match is being re-included but not the leading spaces.

Comment: @Rockwire Have added explanation

Answer (score 1):

your sed command is ok, (the first missing a `*`), I guess you may want the change to be done in your file, so called "in-place" change.

you need the `-i` option for that (gnu sed). it looks like:

```
sed -i 'code' file
```

check man page for detail. for your command, try:

```
sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//' list6.txt
```

note that, `[ \t]` could be written as `\s`

Comment: command `sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//' list6.txt` gives me error `sed: 1: "list6.txt": extra characters at the end of l command`

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD `sed`, which is used on Mac OS X, needs the `-e` switch after the `-i` option to define & recognise the following regex correctly & unambiguously.

```
- sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//' list6.txt
+ sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*//' list6.txt
```